# QTKit Occasionally Crashes When Looking For Devices

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, qtkit

I'm not sure if its just my machine or anyone else having this problem with QTKit. These two methods will occasionally crash. Is there a solution or work around to this?

```
[QTCaptureDevice defaultInputDeviceWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeSound]
[QTCaptureDevice inputDevicesWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeSound]
```

malloc: *** error for object 0x75703e67: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Answer (score 0):

Changing the build to 10.6 solved the problem for me.